# Removing duplicates when parsing Json in JAVA, Hashset not working

Tags: java, json, hashset

I've got a problem I am currently tring to parse a Json file and remove duplicate from it so i thought that i would store it in a Hashset of my Class that hold information but it doesnt remove duplicate.
Can you explain me if I did something wrong of if there is something that I don't understand?

here is a sample of my Code:

```
try {
        FileReader f = new FileReader("E:\\JavaDev\\src\\main\\resources\\annonces.json");
        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(f);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Appartement[] res2 = new Appartement[0];
        res2 = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, res2.getClass());
        Set<Appartement> test = new HashSet<Appartement>(Arrays.asList(res2));

        System.out.println(test.size());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My Appartment look like this:
(getter and setter are removed here to have smaller code)

```
public class Appartement {
private String id;
private Double surface;
private String marketingType;
private Integer roomCount;
private String propertyType;
private Boolean furnished;
private Boolean newBuild;
private String zipCode;
private Double price;
}
```

I tried converting my json directly in a Hashset but I've got an error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

```
HashSet<Appartement> mySet = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, HashSet.class);
```

I verified that there is duplicate in the Json file.

Would apreciate some help here.

Comment: try overriding equals method (requiring appropriate equality checking) and hascode method in your Appartement.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must override equals method of your Appartment class,

See here: [Object equal method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object.equals%28java.lang.Object%29), if you don't override its default equal method, it actually compared the reference of the object,

```
public class Appartement {
    private String id;
    ....

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Appartement)) return false;
        return this.id.equals(((Appartement)obj.id));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

       return 123123131311; //replace to your own hashcode.
    } 
}
```

Joshua, Effective Java

> You must override hashCode() in every class that overrides equals().
>   Failure to do so will result in a violation of the general contract
>   for Object.hashCode(), which will prevent your class from functioning
>   properly in conjunction with all hash-based collections, including
>   HashMap, HashSet, and Hashtable.

Comment: 1. You need to override `hashCode` too, not just because of the convention, but because a `HashSet` actually won't work if you don't and 2. You need to use `instanceof` to check the class of the object passed to `equals`. You can't just cast it directly. People can pass any kind of object to `equals`.

Comment: @Radiodef yes, forgot to add, thanks for the mention.

Comment: I overide both and it's seems to be working because the program took more than 1 min to execute but i still get every json object in my hashset so I dont know what is wrong. I used another method for removing duplicates and it worked but I can't understand why the hash set method isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

`Set<Appartement> test = new HashSet<Appartement>(Arrays.asList(res2));`

You must make sure that Apartment's hashcode and equals method are overridden and you return true from equals method for same Appartement. (based on its properties) otherwise Objects.equals will be called

Answer (score 0):

You need to override equals method (requiring appropriate equality checking) and hascode method in your Appartement.class

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        Appartement[] res2 = {(new HelloWorld()).new Appartement("1"), (new HelloWorld()).new Appartement("2"), (new HelloWorld()).new Appartement("3"),(new HelloWorld()).new Appartement("1") };
        Set<Appartement> test = new HashSet<Appartement>(Arrays.asList(res2));

        System.out.println(test.size());
     }

     public class Appartement {
            private String id;
            private Double surface;
            private String marketingType;
            private Integer roomCount;
            private String propertyType;
            private Boolean furnished;
            private Boolean newBuild;
            private String zipCode;
            private Double price;

            public Appartement(String id){
                this.id=id;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals (Object other)
                {
                    if (!(other instanceof Appartement))
                        return false;
                    Appartement ob = (Appartement) other;
                    return this.id.equals(ob.id) ;
                }

                @Override
                public int hashCode ()
                {
                    return Arrays.hashCode(new String[]{id});
                }
            }
}
```